# RC filter on a clamping circuit

Tags: microcontroller, filter, circuit-analysis

I have designed a clamping circuit to protect pins of my microcontroller and I have to add a low pass RC circuit at the microcontroller end to filter out the high frequency noise. My circuit analysis is weak and I am not sure what part R1 and R21 would play in determining the frequency.

Resistor R1 is used to bias the diodes in a region where their forward voltage is 0.2.
So the node between R1 and R2 is maintained at 3.5 Volts.
R21 is a pull down resistor because the input voltage is 12-20V or open circuit.

[image: Clamping Circuit]

Comment: What is the value of R2?

Comment: R2 and C3 are the resistors and capacitors in a simple RC low pass filter, I need help designing their values.

Comment: Your circuit has some issues.  If for the moment we assume R2 = 0, then pin 3 of D2 will just clamp the node it is attached to to ~ 4V and you will not see any of the input swing.  If R2 is > 0 ohms the same is true but more current runs through the diodes.

Comment: D2 is a Schottky diode, it would clamp the voltage to 3.5 volts. I don't see how changing R2 changes the current through the diode.

Comment: I meant to say that when the input swings to 20 V more current runs through the diode.  In any case, your signal swinging between 12 - 20V won't change the output.  _OR_ does the system operate between ) and Vmax with Vmax being variable between 12-20 V?

Comment: I'm confused about the input.  Is this a signal input? (on and/or off from ground to 12-20 V).. if so what's the signal frequency.   Or is it a power input?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need R2 to form a low pass filter from the 12-20V input - R1 and R21 form an equivalent series R to the capacitor C3. Filter cut-off (ignoring the effects of the diodes) is: -

\$f_C = \dfrac{1}{2\pi R C}\$ where R is the parallel value of R2 and R21 (6.667kohms in your circuit).

So, get rid of R2 and simplify things a bit then, tune the filter by selecting the capacitor value to give the cut-off frequency you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the steady state condition (take out the capacitor)

[image]

The node between R1 and R2 will be held at 3V5 due to the 0.2V drop across the diode (D2 pin 3,2). R2 and R21 form a voltage divider with R2 having a 0.2V drop giving 3V3 at the output.

The purpose of R1 is to drop the input voltage and limit the input current to manageable values. For a 12V input R1 will drop 8v5 (0.425mA), at 20V this drop will be 16V5 (.825mA)

The maximum value for R2 can be calculated (assuming there is no output current taken)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not really correct to talk of a cutoff frequency (in an analog sense) for this circuit, as it is asymmetrical, nonlinear (and the output is digital anyway).

Here's (in simulation) what the output looks like if you feed it a 16V 5kHz square wave (R2 = 510 ohms, C3 = 12nF).

[image]

If you use the simple \$f_c = \frac {1}{2\pi ((R1 + R2) || R21)C}\$ with these values, you get a cutoff frequency of 1.97kHz.

Of course what actually gets through depends on the threshold(s) of the digital circuit- which will vary from unit-to-unit and with temperature. If it's a Schmitt trigger input, the maximum frequency will be a lot lower and more unpredictable because of the typically poorly specified limits to the thresholds.

There will also be somewhat of an effect on the maximum frequency from the actual input voltage level.

Usually with this kind of thing you're probably not trying to hit a certain frequency bang on, but merely pass (for sure) frequencies below a certain threshold, so only the order of magnitude is important. If your maximum frequency is 200Hz, something that blocks signals above a few kHz is likely just fine.